# Modules imported twice. Possible bug in Python interpreter

Tags: python, interpreter

I've made a rather contrived import scheme in a project of mine and I think I might have discovered a bug in the Python interpreter that causes modules to be imported twice.

Here's how my test project is set up:

- /

  - **Launcher.bat** — Project is run from here. It launches 'main/__init__.py` using the Python 3.2 executable
  - **main/__init__.py** — The `__main__` script, the one launched by 'Launcher.bat'
  - **main/foo.py** — Contains an empty class
  - **external/__init__.py** — A script external to the 'main' project scripts, used to demonstrate the problem

**./Launcher.bat**

```
@echo off
C:\Python32\python.exe main\__init__.py
pause
```

**./main/__init__.py**

```
from foo import Foo
print("In 'main', Foo has id:", id(Foo))

# Add the directory from which 'Launcher.bat' was run,
# which is not the same as the './main' directory
# in which this script is located
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '.')


# This script will try to import class Foo, but in doing so
# will casue the interpreter to import this './main/__init__.py'
# script a second time.
__import__('external')
```

**./main/foo.py**

```
class Foo:
    pass
```

**./external/__init__.py**

```
from main.foo import Foo
print("In 'external', Foo has id:", id(Foo))
```

All of this will print the `'Main script was imported'` message twice. If the external script imports any other scripts, those too will be imported twice. I've only tested this on Python 3.2. Is this a bug, or did I make a mistake?

Output of the program is:

> In 'main', Foo has id: 12955136
>   In 'main', Foo has id: 12955136
>   In 'external', Foo has id: 12957456
>   Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: It always make me laugh the statements: my code works, python has a bug :D

Comment: @fabrizioM Then again, you can't really say that you'd expect Python to import the same module twice. I now know why it happens, but I still don't think it should happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `print` is misleading: Since you're not importing, but executing the file at the first time (`__name__ == '__main__'` holds true), the main modules just gets imported once. Move the start point into a secondary file, or check for `__name__ == '__main__'`.

By the way, [circular](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm#circular-imports) [import](http://docs.python.org/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-best-practices-for-using-import-in-a-module) are a bad idea. You should resolve the circular import (by moving foo to a dedicated library). Alternatively, you can make your modules reentrant (i.e. check for the current directory being in `sys.path` before adding it).

Comment: It's not the result of a circular import. I initially discovered this by having a third file, `./main/foo.py`, which both `./main/\__init__.py` and `./external/\__init__.py` imported. I noticed that the classes defined  inside `foo.py` had different `id()` values between the scripts in `main` and the ones in  `external ` (which means the script was imported twice). (But you are right, at a first glace this does look like a circular import problem, I'll fix this.)

Comment: @Paul Manta I'm looking forward to an updated question that does not contain a circular import, and does not fiddle around with import internals (i.e. only the `import` statement)

Comment: @PaulManta Oops, I overlooked another thing: You're *executing* a `main/__init__.py`. Therefore, the module just gets loaded once; the first print is misleading. Updated the answer.

Comment: @PaulManta Huh? The definition of foo doesn't matter. `__init__.py` always gets executed first when importing from somewhere, no matter with what syntax. `from a import b` is only syntactic sugar for `import a; b = a.b; del a`.

Comment: I still don't understand why the `id()` of `Foo` is different between scripts. In CPython it represents the address in memory of the "object". What is an "object"? Is it the data itself, or the handle you have to the data?

Comment: @PaulManta The problem has nothing to do with `id`. There are two instances of the module foo, each with its own class object Foo. I suggest you add `print('foo gets imported, __name__: ' + __name__)` to `foo.py`. That should clear it up.

Comment: @PaulManta An object is an abstract entity (probably what you mean with "the data itself"). CPython chose to implement that by returning the memory address, because it assigns a unique block of memory to each object.

Comment: @philag Thanks. I see the `from ... import` syntax causes the that `print` you gave me to be executed twice (the `import ...` syntax does not). I expected the module to stay in memory for as long as at least one object it contains is referred to by another module.

Comment: @PaulManta You seem to be on the wrong track. This has nothing to do with `from a import b`, which is syntactic sugar as I wrote above. If you replace it with the longer statement, you still get the same result. [Here is the object graph created by your script.](http://phihag.de/2011/so/so-pymodules.svg) (modules only, file names just for reference).

Comment: So whether or not the module was imported before is determined by the module name, not by the file path of the script?

Comment: @PaulManta Precisely. Since some modules don't have filenames, that wouldn't be possible anyways.

Comment: Okay, thanks for helping me. I'll pick yours as an answer, because of the comments.

Comment: @Paul Manta For me, an object is a portion of the RAM memory whose bits are structured in a manner that represents data according to some conventions. A Python object holds bits that conventionally represent a type and bits that conventionally represent a value, said 'its' type and 'its' value. The identity of an object isn't hold in its structure, it is the location where it is lying in the memory. That's my idea. I never understood why the Python doc defines _"Objects are Python’s abstraction for data_". For me, objects are not abstract they are concrete representations of abstract notions.

Comment: @eyquem Well, that holds true for cpython, but does not apply for jython and IronPython.

Comment: @phihag I would like to know more about the implementations of Jython and IronPython. Aren't there objects in these two languages ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's a bug. You should ask on the `python-dev` list for a more authoritative answer. You are executing once (when you run the script) and importing once (from external) so the line gets printed twice. It's not importing twice.

However, this is a horrible setup. There are a lot of style violations here. Granted that some are for demonstration purposes only, it's still quite messy.

1. You shouldn't use a package `__init__.py` file as a file which should be run. The main entry point should be a script that imports the package.
2. You shouldn't have an imported module importing the module which imported it. Like you external is doing to main.

Comment: I know it's a horrible setup, I called it contrived myself. :) It's for demonstration purposes, I tried to do this in as few files as possible. And the module is, in fact, imported twice. If you compare the `id()` of `class Foo` from `main` and the on from `external`, you'll see that they are different.

Comment: @Paul Manta: There is one import of "main", and one _execution_ of main. This explains why you have two versions of Foo being defined. When you execute a script, it does not get imported and cached. To test the theory, create a blank main/__main__.py, and change your launcher script to execute "python -m main".

Comment: The `id`s of classes are orthogonal to the question of imports. You can define a `Foo` class in a module, import another module `x` and have an `x.Foo`. Both will have different `id`s. That's your situation.

Comment: @axw Thanks, I didn't know that. But please check out my updated post, does what you said still apply?

Comment: @PaulManta: Yes. Try adding a `import sys; print('main' in sys.modules)` at the top of external/__init__.py. The "from main.foo import Foo" implicitly imports main/__init__.py since it's not in sys.modules already.

Comment: @awk I see. :) But when `foo.py` is imported, is it not added to sys.modules? I don't understand why Foo has different `id()` values in the two scripts. Doesn't `id()` (in CPython) give you the address in memory of the data itself? &mdash; or is it the address of the handle you have to the data?